# How to maintain URL history when moving forward onto page

Tags: javascript, html5-history

In my index file I add the following code to push a new URL into the history:

```
window.history.pushState(null, '', 'http://localhost:8080/test');
```

When loading the page, I can see that this works and the new URL is correct: `http://localhost:8080/test`

These are the following actions and resulting URLs:

```
[Back Button] => localhost:8080
[Back Button] => example.com
```

That's fine, as expected. However, this is where it gets strange.

```
[Forward Button] => localhost:8080/test (as expected)
[Back Button] => example.com (?!)
```

Where has `localhost:8080` gone in the last action? And how can I keep it in place?

Comment: Why did you expect to get `[Forward Button] => localhost:8080/test` when  you ended up at `example.com`? Shouldn't it be directing to `localhost:8080` ?

Comment: Because the page automatically sets the new state, so you never see `localhost:8080`.